# How to style a list within a menu?

Tags: html, css, list, drop-down-menu, stylesheet

Please hover your mouse over the ***MORE*** button in the menu here: http://jsfiddle.net/XHard/1/ You will see that there is a list containing the words ***New clean list***. I want to style that list but because it is inside the menu, it already has a styling to it.

I want to create a new clean style for it but cannot find a way to do it. I tried playing around with `#mega moreleftbar a` but the original menu list styling is still there.

Is there a way to make a new clean styling for a list inside that menu?

Here is part of my HTML:

```
<div id="second-menu" class="clearfix">
    <ul id="secondary-menu" class="nav sf-js-enabled">
        <li class="manimation"><a href="" style="width:400px;border-bottom:9px solid #43cf61">Animation</a></li>
    </ul>

    <ul id="mega">
        <li class="dif mmore" style="background:none;"><a href="#" style="font-style:italic;border-bottom:9px solid #4b5571">More...</a>
            <div>
                <moretopbar>
                    <ul>
                        <li class="mgames"><a href="" style="border-bottom:9px solid #e34328">Games</a></li>
                        <li class="mliterature"><a href="" style="border-bottom:9px solid #2c8f83">Literature</a></li>
                        <li class="marts"><a href="" style="border-bottom:9px solid #cc226a">Arts</a></li>
                        <li class="mcontact" style="background:none;"><a href="" style="border-bottom:9px solid #9395aa">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </moretopbar>

                <morecontainer>
                    <moreleftbar>

                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="">New clean list 1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">New clean list 2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">New clean list 3</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">New clean list 4</a></li>
                        </ul>

                    </moreleftbar>
                </morecontainer>


            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div> <!-- end #second-menu -->
```

Here is part of my CSS:

```
ul#top-menu li { padding-right: 2px; background: url(images/menu-bg.png) repeat-y top right; }
    ul#top-menu a { font-size: 11px; color: #ffffff; text-decoration: none; text-transform: uppercase; font-weight: bold; text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.7); padding: 16px 12px 10px; }
    ul#top-menu a:hover { color: #ebbe5e;}
    ul#top-menu > li.current_page_item > a { color: #ebbe5e !important; }

    ul#top-menu li ul, #mobile_menu { width: 170px !important; padding: 0; background: #161616 url(images/header-bg.png); top: 45px !important; -moz-box-shadow:3px 3px 7px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1); -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 7px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1); box-shadow: 3px 3px 7px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1); -moz-border-radius: 10px; -webkit-border-radius: 10px; border-radius: 10px; border-top-left-radius: 0px;-moz-border-radius-topleft: 0px; border-top-right-radius: 0px; -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 0px; -moz-border-radius-topright: 0px; -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 0px; z-index: 9999px; display: none; }
        ul#top-menu ul li, #mobile_menu li a { margin: 0 !important; padding: 10px 7px 10px 25px !important; background: url(images/top-menu-separator.png) repeat-x; }
        ul#top-menu ul li.first-item { background: none; }
            ul#top-menu ul li a, #mobile_menu a { padding: 0 !important; width: 138px; }

            ul#top-menu li:hover ul ul, ul#top-menu li.sfHover ul ul { top: -1px !important; left: 171px !important; -moz-border-radius: 8px; -webkit-border-radius: 8px; border-radius: 8px; }

    ul#top-menu li.menu-gradient { background: url("images/top-shadow.png") repeat-x; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 202px; height: 7px !important; }

ul#secondary-menu li { background: url(images/secondary-menu-bg.png) repeat-y top right; }
    ul#secondary-menu a { font-size: 16px; color: #48423f; text-decoration: none; text-transform: uppercase; font-weight: bold; padding: 22px 16px; }
    ul#secondary-menu a:hover { color: #ffffff; text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 #404747; }
    #second-menu ul.nav li:hover a {color: #ffffff; text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 #404747; }

    ul#secondary-menu > li.current_page_item > a { color: #919e9e !important; }    

    ul#secondary-menu li ul, #category_mobile_menu { width: 360px !important; padding: 7px 0 10px; background: #fff url(images/content-bg.png); top: 55px !important; -moz-box-shadow:3px 3px 7px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1); -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 7px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1); box-shadow: 3px 3px 7px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1); -moz-border-radius: 10px; -webkit-border-radius: 10px; border-radius: 10px; border-top-left-radius: 0px;-moz-border-radius-topleft: 0px; border-top-right-radius: 0px; -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 0px; -moz-border-radius-topright: 0px; -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 0px; z-index: 9999px; display: none; }
        ul#secondary-menu ul li, #category_mobile_menu li a { margin: 0 !important; padding: 8px 0 8px 30px !important; width: 150px; float: left; }
            ul#secondary-menu ul li a, #category_mobile_menu a { padding: 0 !important; }

            ul#secondary-menu li:hover ul ul, ul#secondary-menu li.sfHover ul ul { top: -8px !important; left: 180px !important; -moz-border-radius: 8px; -webkit-border-radius: 8px; border-radius: 8px; }
            ul#secondary-menu ul li.even-item { background: none; }


.manimation:hover{
    background:#43cf61 !important;
}
.mmore:hover{
    background:#4b5571 !important;
}
.mliterature:hover{
    background:#2c8f83 !important;
}
.mgames:hover{
    background:#e34328 !important;
}
.marts:hover{
    background:#cc226a !important;
}
.mcontact:hover{
    background:#9395aa !important;
}

/* ---------- Mega Drop Down --------- */
ul#mega li { padding-right: 0px; background: url(images/secondary-menu-bg.png) repeat-y top right; }

#mega {
list-style:none;
font-weight:bold;
height:2em;

}
#mega li {
padding: 23px 0px;
background:#999;
border:0px solid #000;
float:left;
text-align:center;
position:relative;
}
#mega li:hover {
background:#eee;
border-bottom:0; /* border-bottom:0; and padding-bottom:1px; keeps <li> and <div> connected */
z-index:1; /* shadow above adjacent li */

}
#mega a { font-size: 16px; color: #48423f; text-decoration: none; text-transform: uppercase; font-weight: bold; padding: 22px 16px;}

ul#mega a:hover { color: #FFFFFF; text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 #404747; }



/* ----------- Hide/Show Div ---------- */
#mega div {
    -moz-border-bottom-colors: none;
    -moz-border-image: none;
    -moz-border-left-colors: none;
    -moz-border-right-colors: none;
    -moz-border-top-colors: none;
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
    border-color: -moz-use-text-color #48423F #48423F;
    border-right: 1px solid #48423F;
    border-style: none solid solid;
    border-width: 0 1px 1px;
    font-weight: normal;
    left: -999em;
    margin-top: 1px;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: left;
    width: 496px;
}
/* --------- Within Div Styles --------- */
#mega li:hover div {
    left: -1px;
    top: auto;
}
#mega li.dif:hover div {
    left: -407px;
    top: 72px;
}
#mega li.mmore:hover > a {
    color: #FFFFFF; text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 #404747; /* Ensures hover on MORE remains */
}
#mega div h2 {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #999999;
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    font-size: 1em;
    margin: 10px 0 5px;
    padding: 0 10px;
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
}
#mega div moretopbar {
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
margin-left:1px;
margin-right:1px;
    width: 495px;
    height: 74px;
    background-image: url(images/morebgwide.png);
    background-size:495px 74px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
#mega div p {
    float: left;
    padding-left: 10px;
    position: relative;
    width: 106px;
}
#mega div p a {
    clear: left;
    float: left;
    line-height: 1.4;
    text-decoration: underline;
    width: 100%;
}
#mega div a:hover, #mega div a:focus, #mega div a:active {
    text-decoration: none;
}
#mega div morecontainer {
    width: 495px;
}
#mega div moreleftbar {
    width: 70%;
}

#mega moreleftbar a { /* I want to style the list here - clean slate*/
    margin-left: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #cc6600;
}
```

Although, I would advice overlooking the fiddle for a visual presentation of the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/XHard/1/

There must be a way to make a new clean list in that drop down menu. Can you figure out how? If you will answer, please be detailed as my coding knowledge is limited - ideally with an updated fiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so just had a look at firebugs output on the styling of the `<ul>` tag you have. And the CSS rules are specific to the `<ul>` tags within `#mega`.

So I added this CSS that targets the UL you want to style and reset a few rules:

```css
ul#mega moreleftbar ul,
ul#mega moreleftbar ul li,
ul#mega moreleftbar ul li a,
ul#mega moreleftbar ul li a:hover
{
    padding:0;
    border:0;
    margin:0;
    color:#000000;
    font-size:inherit;
    font-weight:normal;
    background:none;
}
```

[JSfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/aCMwr/)

Notice your original rule for styling the `<li>`

```css
ul#mega li
```

This will be overwritten by the targetted rules I've applied above.

By being more specific with the rules, they overwrite less specific styles (unless a style has an !important tagged to it).

```css
.manimation:hover{
    background:#43cf61 !important;
}
```

The above rule for example will stop you being able to apply any further background-color changes to any elements that are covered by the rule. `!important` is not a good thing to use unless it is absolutely necessary.

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer, works almost perfectly, I added 'text-shadow: none;' to reset the 1px text shadow. **However**, there is still a grey background when you hover each list item, where can I reset that? I tried browsing through Firebug without any results, can you kindly find it? I have upvoted this answer and will accept it as correct if you can.

Comment: Yes the grey background is not applied by standard CSS at all. Neither are any of the other hover background colors in your dropwdown. My guess is it is applied with Jquery, there are alot of scripts included in your example and you will need to find out where it is applied.

Comment: I added this to the list item: **<li style="background:none;">** it seemed to fix it, although with this solution, I will be forced to use it inline.

Comment: Well as I see it, you either isolate the problem in your JS / Jquery and fix as you see fit. Alternatively: `background:none !important;` in the style rule rather than consistently inline. If you are going to do that, make the rule more explicit to ONLY target that ul by giving it an ID or class and adding that to the rule before using !important.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, I have accepted it as the correct one. Cheers!